# Simple equation need explain

Tags: calculus, analysis

Can anyone please explain me why this equation is true:

$$f(x) = \ln(x-(x^3-1)^{1/3}) = \ln\left(\frac{1}{x^2+x\cdot(x^3-1)^{1/3}+(x^3-1)^{2/3}}\right)$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$~a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

$$a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$$

with

$$a=x\;,\;\;b=\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}$$

Comment: Do you mean $a=x$ ?

Comment: @PeterPhipps no. $a=\sqrt[3]x$

Comment: @Sabyasachi, But don't we want $a-b = x - (x^3-1)^{1/3}$ and $a^3-b^3 = 1$ ?

Comment: @PeterPhipps Yes we do. And if you take $a=\sqrt[3]x=x^{1/3}\;,\;\;b=\sqrt[3]{x^3-1}$ you *do* get $a^3-b^3=1$

Comment: @Sabyasachi, No you don't, you get $x - (x^3 - 1)$. The $x$s cancel only if $a=x$.

Comment: @PeterPhipps oh right. My bad.

Comment: @PeterPhipps , you're right. Thanks, edited.